# My atom packages are not providing me error highlighting for Elm

Tags: atom-editor, elm

I have installed several packages to get error highlighting among other things these worked on my Windows computer but I can't get it to work on my new Mac from work.

I am using Elm 0.18 and have the following packages

```
busy-signal
elm-format
intentions
language-elm (with elm-oracle)
linter
linter-elm-make
linter-ui-default
minimap
```

I will be honest I am not 100% sure which one of those packages should highlight my errors I was following a guide from a video in order to know which packages to install.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using v0.18? 0.19 is the current release and there are quite significant changes between the two. If you had 0.19, you could also use the elm-language-server that provides code diagnostics, refactoring tools, etc.

https://github.com/elm-tooling/elm-language-server
https://github.com/atom/atom-languageclient

Comment: Yes there is.... The main reason is that is what I am told we are using. :P I believe it is something to do with WebSocket support between 18 and 19 and the fact that we don't have the manpower to switch to 19 yet.

Comment: I have no experience in working with 0.18. Have you checked the page of `linter-elm-make` if all your settings are correct? https://atom.io/packages/linter-elm-make

Also, there's a similar question here in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712232/cant-get-atom-linter-to-work?rq=1

Comment: I've been using [elmjutsu](https://atom.io/packages/elmjutsu) with Atom for a while, and if I remember correctly I used it with 0.18 as well. It integrates with linter and gives some nice additional features as well.

Comment: In some packages (like elm-format), you can chose the Elm version you want to use in the settings of the package (for example it was by default on 0.19 for elm-format).

Comment: I use "elmjutsu" and I can see in the options, there are still field available for setting it for Elm 0.18. Not sure about elm-format. Maybe you need to install an old version of it.